# Why do we need both Future and Promise?

Tags: scala, jvm, promise, future

As I know, `Future` is read-only and `Promise` is write-once data structure.

We need a `Promise` to complete a `Future`

For example,

```
object Lie extends Throwable

val lie = Future { throw Lie } 

val guess = Promise[String]()     

lie.onComplete { case Success(s) => guess.success("I knew it was true!") 
                 case Failure(t) => guess.failure("I knew it was lie")} 
// return type: Unit 

guess.future.map(println) 
// res12: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = List()
// I knew it was lie!
// Requires Promise to chain Future with exception
```

But, I can't understand why we need to have both `Future` and `Promise`

I guess `Promise` is required because of `Future.onComplete` signature

Since `Future.onComplete` return type is `Unit`,`Future` with possible exceptions cannot be chained

I assume `Promise` was introduced to overcome this limitation

But why not just change the signature of `Future.onComplete` ?

Changing the return type of `Future.onComplete` as `Future[T]` will enable chaining on `Future` with exception

and then, `Future` does not need `Promise`

For example, code above can be changed into

```
val lie = Future { throw Lie } 

lie.onComplete { 
   case Success(s) => "I knew it was true!"
   case Failure(t) => "I knew it was lie!"
}.map(println) 

//onComplete return type is Future[String]
```

My question is

1) am I right? does `Future` not need `Promise` , If onComplete signature is changed from `Unit` to `Future[T]`?

2) Why Future and Promise are divided in the first place ?

**UDPATE**

Thanks to the repliers, Now I understand the purpose of Promise. It wasn't actually for `Future` chaining

If I may, can I ask you

Why `onComplete` returns `Unit` ??

It can actually return `Future[T]` to enable chaining Future easily

For example

```
Future { throw Error }.onComplete {
  case Success(s) => "Success" 
  case Failure(t) => throw Error
}.onComplete {
  case Success(s) => "Success"
  case Failure(t) => throw Error 
}. ...
```

Comment: (regarding your UPDATE); you probably want the `transform` method that's new in 2.12, see here: https://github.com/viktorklang/blog/blob/master/Futures-in-Scala-2.12-part-3.md (the other articles in this "blog" are also worth reading)

Comment: @Fabian thanks Fabian, This is the best answer to me

Comment: Unfortunately Java 8's authors concluded we don't need to separate the two concepts (aka `CompletableFuture`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> am I right? does `Future` not need `Promise` , If `onComplete` signature is
>   changed from Unit to Future[T]?

You're mixing things up a little. Let's clarify.

A `Future[T]` represents a computation which will complete in the future. That is, you pass `Future.apply` a function which will execute on a thread assigned by some `ExecutionContext` you define.

Now, on the other hand, a `Promise[T]` is a way to *create a `Future[T]`*, without actually creating a `Future[T]`. A good example for this would be the `Future.successful` method (which will internally consume `Promise.successful`):

```
def successful[T](result: T): Future[T] = Promise.successful(result).future
```

This requires no `ExecutionContext` and no queuing if any additional resources. It's merely a convenience wrapper that allows you to "artificially" create a `Future[T]`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it helps me to understand better.

Comment: Kinda funny. "This requires no ExecutionContext and no queuing if any additional resources. It's merely a convenience wrapper that allows you to "artificially" create a Future[T]." Well because to produce `result` you had to use a thread. Now when it's completed, you show us how to use the redundant Promise API in order to wrap `result` in an already completed Future. This by no means a good reason to have both Promise and Future APIs. Promise may have been okay to remain as an internal implementation detail, but I don't see any reason for it to be exposed to the developer.

Comment: @rapt Lets assume you had some code which wraps some native code. This function does some some work, perhaps asynchronously using some C thread, and you wanted to pass it some `void*` to invoke when completed (some arbitrary handler). A `Promise` would allow you to defer control of the completion to that code, since only it knows when the operation completes.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I am not sure I got your idea right - and I was only referring to the OP question in the Scala environment - but it looks to me like what you are trying to do can (also) be done by `Future.onComplete`. BTW I think the Promise itself does not know WHEN the operation completes (onComplete), it only knows IF it was completed (isCompleted). The definition of Promise you gave is good. I think a clearer definition would be: "Promise is a factory of a Future." But it's confusing that the Promise is often completed (i.e. updated) by another Future.

Answer (score 7):

`Future.apply[T](block: => T): Future[T]` is syntactic sugar for `Future.unit.map(_ => block)`[1]

A `Future` represents a *value* which may or may not be *currently* available.

A `Promise` represents the obligation to provide such a value *at some point*.

Having separate entities for `Future` (for reads) and `Promise` (for writes) means that it is easy to reason about capabilities:

- When a Future is a parameter, it is a request to have some value *at some point* and when it is used as a return type, it's a response which may not be currently available.
- When a Promise is a parameter, it is the "consumption" of responsibility of producing some value at some point, and when it is used as a return type it is the "production" of responsibility to produce the value at some point.

All in all, being able to reason about capabilities, especially in asynchronous, or even concurrent programs, is extremely valuable.

Most of the time Promises need not be used, since that is transparently handled by the Future-combinators—but when integrating with third party software or networking libraries it can be extremely useful.

For more information about interesting new features in Scala 2.12, have a look [here](https://github.com/viktorklang/blog).

1: Where `Future.unit`
is defined as:
`val unit: Future[Unit] = Future.successful(())`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is very helpful! But what is the ***Future.unit***?? It is not explained in api docs

Comment: @wonpyoPark That's explained in the footnote. For more info, look at the link to the more news in scala 2.12 in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No.

`Future`cannot cover the use cases of `Promise`. `Promise` has its own value. You cannot replace `Future` with `Promise`.

`Future` represents a computation which is available at a later point of time. You can get the result using `onComplete` once the future execution is complete and you can compose futures using `map`, `flatMap`, `recover`  and `recoverWith`.

> Promise is one time write container, clients can subscribe to the container. When subscribed client gets a future to wait until value is written into that container called promise.

Future is read-only

> You cannot use future as one time write container. You can only read from future.

But `Promise` is different.

> What if you want to give user something, which you do not have right now but you think you will have it soon ?

That means you are promising user something which you do not have right now.

So you want to keep the user waiting till you have the thing which you will give it to user. Thats when you do `p.future` and generate a future so that user can wait for the result using the future.

Once you have the result which you promised to give the user, You give to user by making the future a `success` or `failure` when something bad happens (i.e by doing `p.complete`).

> Even if `onComplete` return type is changed to `Future[T]`. `Future` cannot act like or serve purpose of `Promise`.

#### Creating future using Future companion object

Future can be created by using `Future.apply` also. In this case future created would be complete once the computation inside the future finishes.

> Future is used to subscribe to the result of the time-consuming computation, whereas Promise can be a publish and subscribe model.

Comment: thank you for answer, did you read my question after I edited ? 
can you be more specific to my question about onComplete signature (return type)

Comment: @WonpyoPark.  Even if `onComplete` return type is changed to `Future[T]`. `Future` cannot act like or serve purpose of `Promise`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thanks to you, I understand purpose of Promise

Comment: @pamu You did not explain what you can do only with Promise but not with Future. You seemed to be promising an explanation but there was none coming.

Comment: @rapt added it now.

Comment: @pamu It is not clear what you try to say. Is it clear to you? First, clients are not normally supposed to have access to the Promise. They should only access the Future. It is the task implementer who uses the Promise to update its status with either Success or Failure, when the task completes. Second, I ask why do we need to expose Promise to the developer? Future will update its status anyway to success/failure when it completes, even if I as a developer know nothing about Promise (although internally it's done by updating the corresponding Promise).

Comment: @rapt try to use promise api and you will understand what I want to say.

Comment: @rapt client get future creating from `promise.future` and this future will complete when a value is written into promise.

Comment: @rapt Future created by `promise.future` will never complete if a value is not written into the promise. There is no harm in clients accessing the promise.

Comment: @rapt Please use the promise api and everything will be clear

Comment: @pamu "Future created by promise.future will never complete if a value is not written into the promise." Yes but who told you to create a Future by promise.future? You can create it by Future.apply. "There is no harm in clients accessing the promise." You really want to let clients tell the server when a task is completed?!?!?

Comment: @rapt 1) I have written in the answer that future is being created by using `promise.future` 2) clients can access the `promise` meaning to the extent it is permissible by the domain. There are things that you have to infer from the answer. If you want to improve the answer please go ahead and edit. If not write ur own answer. I am not here to argue nitty gritty details.

Comment: @pamu and I have written that this does not prove that Promise is essential, since Future can be created by Future.apply.

Comment: @pamu All good but you have not shown that "Future cannot cover the use cases of Promise. Promise has its own value. You cannot replace Future with Promise." What you did is called Hand-waving.

Comment: @rapt "Future is read-only.

You cannot use future as one time write container. You can only read from future."

Comment: @rapt "Future is used to subscribe to the result of the time-consuming computation, whereas Promise can be a publish and subscribe model."