# Scala: Is Promise redundant?

Tags: scala, promise, future

A related question: [Why do we need both Future and Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331668/why-do-we-need-both-future-and-promise/40331799)

If I understand the Scala Future/Promise API right, Future and Promise have a one-to-one relationship between them, and it's possible to go from a promise to its corresponding future, but not vice versa.

In the code examples that I have seen so far, Promise may be used by the (asynchronous) task implementer, but what that is returned to eventually the client is the corresponding Future to read the result from.

This makes sense, since as a task implementer, I do not want to allow the client the ability do set the task as completed, only to read its result when its completed.

So Promise is often described as essential due to being the way for the task implementer to update/write (once only) the result of the task, and Future as the way to read the result by the client.

I understand why Promise may be useful or "okay to have" as an internal implementation detail of Future.

But is it actually essential to expose Promise as a public API to the developer? As a task implementer, I can create the required Future without the Promise API, simply by `Future.apply`.

In the code block that I pass to `Future.apply` I can decide what to return as a successful result, and when to throw exceptions. This is equivalent to what I can do with Promise.

It seems to me like originally there was only something like Promise, with an additional ability to query the Promise for the completed result (value/exception) which now has been delegated to Future. And only later Future was added to the API, but for some reason Promise was kept exposed.

So my question is, is there anything essential in Promise that cannot be done by Future, or is Promise redundant?

Pay attention: I am not asking if Promise and Future are two different concepts which justify different entities. I am asking if Promise provides a practical ability that cannot be achieved by Future alone.

Answer (score 2):

Let's give this a try...

`Promise` allow completing `Future`s based on **external** events/triggers.

Imagine you are using a service to which you post orders, those orders need a long time to execute so you will only get feedback (the result of the execution) much later.

How would you handle that with `Future` only? You would need to constantly poll for the result (from the `Future.apply` body).

Using a `Promise`, you could wait for the service to trigger a callback once done. When that trigger happens, you can complete the `Future` using the `Promise`. You complete the `Future` from outside of the `Future.apply` body, that's what I meant above by **external** events/trigger.

In other words, a `Promise` is a safe way to complete a `Future` from outside, and there's no other way to do it: the `Promise` API is essential.

Comment: @rapt what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `Promise` to some other part of code and allow it to complete the `Future` when and how it wants.

> As a task implementer, I can create the required Future without the Promise API, simply by Future.apply.

You may just want to create `Future`s. But other people need to write functions which work with `Future`s, and *they* need `Promise`.

Comment: "functions which work with Futures" - Do you mean functions that may try to complete Futures?

Comment: No, I mean e.g. `Future` combinators: functions which take `Future`s and return `Future`s. You can see many in the standard library, but that doesn't mean you can't write your own.

Comment: Your first sentence does say "pass a Promise to some other part of code and allow it to complete the Future when and how it wants." That does sound to me like "functions that may try to complete Futures". Yes it's common to see methods that take a Future and return a new Future. I don't think I have seen in the standard library an example of a method which gets a Promise (and hence its Future) as a parameter. Do you have an example? I see a lot of methods that accept Future as parameter (not Promise), but AFAIK this means they cannot on their own retrieve the Promise out of the Future. ...

Comment: ... Also it looks quite an anti-pattern to me if I give somebody A a Future I created, and then I give somebody else B a direct access to its corresponding Promise. So B can externally anytime try to be the first to complete the Future, without A being aware of it (simply by looking at the Future code). .... If A and B are actually the same person, first, it's enough only to give the Promise, and second, if they want to force their result, they can just create it as a new Future, so again they don't need the Promise.

Comment: Put it the other way around: I create a `Promise`, not a `Future`. Then I give the promise to B, and give its corresponding `Future` to A (so "the Future code" is just `promise.future`, and if A looks at the code, they certainly can be aware of it). It isn't that B can "try to be the first to complete the future", it's the only way to complete the future: that's the point.

Comment: First, any example of standard lib method that accepts Promise? Second, yes, but then B may give the Promise to C, who may give it to D. You simply delegated your local main logic to B, and made your comfort zone of "the main logic" one layer wider. By making it a legitimate pattern to write methods that give/get promises to/from other methods, you open the door to an unmanageable code. So we have a dangerous API that should be avoided. And maybe even redundant.